# Getting list of local file names that match certain criteria in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to make an extension where users get notifications about old files on their systems that they forgot to delete/no longer need. However, I want to get a list of file names in my computer that satisfy this criteria (which is going to be based upon some date) and I am unsure of how I can use node js to do so. I tried watching tutorials but all the ones I have seen show how to read/write to files that are saved in the user's VS code or code editor. I am looking to get a list of file names from my downloads or documents folder and if I want to delete them it just deletes them in place.

Can someone give me some pointers on how I can achieve this functionality using node js or any other tool?

I have only tried watching tutorials so far because this is my first time using js.

Comment: Take a look at `fs` package: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options